# New-AzureRmResource : InternalServerError : Encountered an internal server error. while creating cloud service through Azure Powershell 5.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell

Getting below error while creating cloud Service through Azure Powershell 5.0.0

And I am able to create cloud service though portal for the same input.

Does anybody have any idea. the same code was working perfectly fine last  couple of months. but since couple of days i am seeing this error.

```
[DBG]: PS D:\MSTeams\Source\Repos\SkypeSpaces-Infra\tools\Azure>> New-AzureRmResource -Name $ServiceName -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames" -Location $Location.Location -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Force:$Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-AzureRmResource : InternalServerError : Encountered an internal server error. The tracking id is '862cb19d-4485-4ef8-a847-657beaeb7c90'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResource -Name $ServiceName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Class ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InternalServerError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceCmdlet
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make sure you are running the latest version of of PowerShell? I find weird errors pop up when the version is out of date. Also, if you can share an example of your code that would be useful.

Comment: look at the logs on portal, find whats the error using that id. post the code that is causing this. also, wth is `$location.location` ;)

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` use the cmdlet get Azure Power Shell version. I test in the latest version, I get the same result with you. If possible, could you show your full script.